# Run mvn exec:exec without a pom.xml

Tags: maven

I am trying to find a way just to fetch a library from maven repository and run it. I want to define everything by command line and ignore the pom. I am trying following:

```
 mvn exec:exec -Dexec.mainClass="org.main.Class" -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

When I try to run it with pom.xml, it starts to fetch all the dependencies described in the pom. Which I really don't want. When I run it without the pom.xml, it says `Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory. Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.` Is there a way to run it without the pom or at least ignore it?

My goal is just to start my application from anywhere without sources or jars.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-DrequiresProject=false`?

Comment: I just tried, but still the same `Goal requires a project to execute...`

Comment: Another option is to create a separate profile in pom.xml with only `maven-exec-plugin` in it and another profile which is activated by default with all dependencies and all other plugins.

Answer (score 7):

One possible workaround would be to:

- first get the jar
- then execute it

For that, the [maven plugin `dependency:get`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) is handy, and can be executed without any pom.xml/project (so from any folder you want)

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get -DrepoUrl=https://dtp.intramundi.com/nexus/repository/maven-central/ -Dartifact=<group>:<artifact>:<version>
```

Once you have copied the artifact to the folder of your choice, a plugin like [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency:copy-dependencies_mojo) could, reading the pom.xml of the artifact you just got, copy said dependencies to the same folder of your choice.

Finally, a `java -cp . yourArtifact.jar` can execute it.

I realize this is not as straightforward as just "`exec:exec`", and that it fetches dependencies from the `pom.xml`, but here at least:

- the first step does not require any `pom.xml`,
- the second step needs the `pom.xml` of the very artifact you want to execute, and those dependencies might be needed at runtime: you would need those anyway if you want to '`exec`' your artifact.

Comment: Can I specific the classifier in the `-Dartifact` part?

Comment: @NanoNova Yes, considering the artifact is a string of the form `groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging[:classifier]]`. But you can also use `--classifier=...`. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html

Comment: thx, missing the packaging part killed me.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's impossible. Mvn Exec is, in fact, Maven Pluging dedicated to execute something as part of maven-nature project. If you need to execute Jar outcome why not use just `java ***.jar` ?

Comment: Because the classpath won't be set up with all the transitive dependencies necessary to execute the code in that jar.