# Can I run maven artifact from docker

Tags: javascript, maven, docker, rhino

My goal is to setup a Dockerfile with maven:latest in order to be able to run my javascript code with the latest build of `org.mozilla.rhino`

```
FROM maven:latest
RUN [ "mvn", "dependency:get", "-Dartifact=org.mozilla:rhino:LATEST:jar" ]
RUN [ "mvn", "exec:java" "-Dexec.mainClass='org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main'" "-Dexec.args='src/index.js'"]
```

do I need a pom.xml in order to do that and if I do
**what should my pom.xml contain since my project only has javascript files?**

PS: I have no previous experience with maven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run mvn exec:exec without a pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412738/run-mvn-execexec-without-a-pom-xml)

Comment: The question quoted above partially answers my question, but I need some help with my `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you had hoped, you don't really need a `pom.xml` for your project. I don't know if you need this to be fully portable, but here's something I mocked up based on `maven:latest`. This is done by taking advantage of the fact that the rhino jar file which is downloaded contains a `MANIFEST.MF` file that tells a `java` command how to execute it.

**contents of rhino-1.7.10.jar:/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Implementation-Version: 1.7.10
Implementation-Title: Mozilla Rhino
Implementation-Vendor: Mozilla Foundation
Implementation-URL: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino
Built-Date: 2018-04-09
Built-Time: 20:03:34
```

So:

**index.js**

```
print("Hello world");
```

**command line**

```
$ mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.mozilla:rhino:LATEST:jar # as you have currently
... # maven output snipped
$ find .m2 -name rhino*.jar -exec java -jar {} index.js \;
Hello world!
```

**Dockerfile** (untested)

```
FROM maven:latest
# Missing here is you copying your javascript into the image
RUN [ "mvn", "dependency:get", "-Dartifact=org.mozilla:rhino:LATEST:jar" ]
RUN [ "find", "/root/.m2", "-name", "rhino*.jar", "-exec", "java", "-jar", "{}", "src/index.js", "\;" ]
```

Edit:

I should also note that the `.m2` user subdirectory contains a repository that houses all the artifacts which maven downloads. The `maven:latest` Dockerfile appears to set this up under /root/.